# Domain user automatic autentication for intranet

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, reporting-services

I'm developing an intranet application. The application is working on an IIS on a windows server 2008. I'm using C# for coding the ASP.NET.

So, I only want to allow the domain users who are member of the OU ICT.
I don't want a login form, just an automatic authentication.

Sql Server Reporting Services works like this. Users don't have to login and the security is based on the AD. -> exactly what I'm looking for.

I have tried several ways, like with WidowsImpersonationContext I hit a dead-end on the OU.

If there would be anyone who can help me, I would be very thankful.

Solved the part where I check if the user is in the group/ou.

### But I can't get the windows user from the client machine without logging in.

Greetings, Jeff

Comment: Isn't that to much hussle just to check if the user is in an OU?

Comment: What authentication do I have to use on the IIS? Only windows or anonymous also?

Comment: @Jeff, if you can put all users from OU into specific AD Group then you can use windows authentication followed by `WindowsPrincipal.IsInRole` method to do access control.

Comment: @VinayC Thanks for the tip the IsInRole is working if i debug it on my visual studio but it does not work on my IIS then it throws System.InvalidOperationException: An anonymous identity cannot perform an impersonation. on WindowsImpersonationContext wic = wi.Impersonate();

Comment: Sill how do I get the user to be authenticated and not be anonymous without inputting the login and username in a loginform..

Comment: I found the solution, group policy implements a proxy. And the inlog box didn't popup because of the proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I´m not to sure about the mixture between OU´s and Groups here, but maybe the following will help you:

Reference System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement,

```c#
        var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain); 

        var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, IdentityType.SamAccountName,"DOMAIN\\USER");

        var g = System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, IdentityType.DistinguishedName, "Everyone");

        var check = user.IsMemberOf(g);
```

HTH
Dominik

Comment: That part I got working with this code: WindowsPrincipal myPrincipal = new WindowsPrincipal((WindowsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity);

        if (myPrincipal.IsInRole(@"domain\group")) { 
        
        }